# (React, Formik, Yup) How to create a Yup schema for the FieldArray?

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I have a form to create a course with authors.
[Form with one Author](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFPXq.png)
| [Form with two Authors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00MUV.png)

How'd you create a Yup schema for the array of authors? It should be an Array of the Authors (minimum one author, capital Name and Surname).

That's my basic schema, when it was a single input:

```
const COURSE_SCHEMA = yup.object().shape({
    title: yup
        .string()
        .min(2, 'Too Short!')
        .max(16, 'Too Long!')
        .required('Required'),
    description: yup
        .string()
        .min(24, 'Too Short!')
        .max(124, 'Too Long!')
        .required('Required'),
    authors: yup.string().required('Required'),
    duration: yup
        .number('Paste the duartion time in minutes')
        .integer('The number has to be integer')
        .min(15, 'At least 15 minutes!')
        .max(300, 'Maximum duration is 300 minutes!')
        .required('Required'),
});

const yupSchemas = {
    // loginSchema: LOGIN_SCHEMA,
    // registrationSchema: REGISTERATION_SCHEMA,
    courseSchema: COURSE_SCHEMA,
};
```

Formik init:

```
<Formik
    validationSchema={yupSchemas.courseSchema}
    initialValues={{
      title: '',
      description: '',
      authors: [''],
      duration: '',
    }}
//-----------------
```

That's my dynamic multivalue input. It was made by this [Formik's template](https://codesandbox.io/s/1o8n593z6q?file=/field-array.js:625-1852):

```
<FormStrap.Group className='mb-3' controlId='course-authors'>
                                <FormStrap.Label>Authors</FormStrap.Label>
                                <FieldArray
                                    name='authors'
                                    render={(arrayHelpers) => (
                                        <Box>
                                            {values.authors && values.authors.length > 0 ? (
                                                values.authors.map((authors, index) => (
                                                    <Box key={index}>
                                                        <Field
                                                            className='form-control'
                                                            name={`authors.${index}`}
                                                            type='text'
                                                            placeholder='Name Surname'
                                                        />
                                                        <Button
                                                            className='mt-1'
                                                            variant='success'
                                                            size='sm'
                                                            onClick={() => arrayHelpers.insert(index, '')}
                                                        >
                                                            +
                                                        </Button>{' '}
                                                        <Button
                                                            className='mt-1'
                                                            variant='danger'
                                                            size='sm'
                                                            onClick={() => arrayHelpers.remove(index)}
                                                            disabled={values.authors.length === 1}
                                                        >
                                                            -
                                                        </Button>
                                                    </Box>
                                                ))
                                            ) : (
                                                <Button onClick={() => arrayHelpers.push('')}>
                                                    Add an Author
                                                </Button>
                                            )}
                                        </Box>
                                    )}
                                />
                            </FormStrap.Group>
```

Comment: You are looking for `yup.array()...`

Comment: `authors: yup.array().of(yup.string())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one was a right answer. Thanks to Usama.

```
authors: yup.array().of(yup.string())
```